# Remove values in the middle of the map

Tags: qgis

[image]I added the coordinates in the map but values in the middle of the map overlap. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Some more details on how you added them would be helpful.

Comment: Under draw coordinates, I selected show longitude only, outside the frame, horizontal for left, right, top, and bottom.

Comment: And you're talking about the print composer, I guess?

Comment: In layouts....I don't know how to add a picture in comment to clarify.

Comment: You can't add pictures to the comments, but you can edit your question.

Comment: Thank you...I've already added the map.

Comment: What CRS is your map?

Comment: EPSG: 102016 North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant

Comment: I had no answer yet.